# Check a .zip archive integrity/filepaths/compression methods from python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, zip, web-widget

I need to verify if an widget which basically is a .zip are according  to this compliance rules:
http://www.w3.org/TR/widgets/#zip-archive

So what I need is to be able to check in that archive:

- Compression Methods;
- Version of Zip Needed to Extract a File Entry;
- Zip Relative Paths (path lengths, character encoding, filenames)

What would be the way to approach this from python(what lib to use, some minimal code example would help)?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/library/index.html

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams it seems it has anything I need especially ZipInfo Objects, any example code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use the `zipfile` lib - try this http://bip.weizmann.ac.il/course/python/PyMOTW/PyMOTW/docs/zipfile/index.html:

To test if the file is a zip file:

```
import zipfile

for filename in [ 'README.txt', 'example.zip', 
                  'bad_example.zip', 'notthere.zip' ]:
    print '%20s  %s' % (filename, zipfile.is_zipfile(filename))
```

And to access the info of a zip file:

```
import datetime
import zipfile

def print_info(archive_name):
    zf = zipfile.ZipFile(archive_name)
    for info in zf.infolist():
        print info.filename
        print '\tComment:\t', info.comment
        print '\tModified:\t', datetime.datetime(*info.date_time)
        print '\tSystem:\t\t', info.create_system, '(0 = Windows, 3 = Unix)'
        print '\tZIP version:\t', info.create_version
        print '\tCompressed:\t', info.compress_size, 'bytes'
        print '\tUncompressed:\t', info.file_size, 'bytes'
        print

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print_info('example.zip')
```